# piechart along with infoBox() shinyApp dataframe error

Tags: r, shiny, pie-chart, shinydashboard

I wanted to render pie chart based on the data showing in infoBox(). The shinyApp should display result in infobox as well as by piechart.

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ECharts2Shiny)

a <- 10
b <- 20
dat1 <- data.frame(a,b)
colnames(dat1) <- c("Male", "Female")

c <- 20
d <- 20
dat2 <- data.frame(c,d)
colnames(dat2) <- c("Male", "Female")

e <- 30
f <- 20
dat3 <- data.frame(e,f)
colnames(dat3) <- c("Male", "Female")

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "123"),
    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(radioButtons("Ben", "Details", c("1","2", "3"), inline = T), 
    infoBoxOutput("loc", width = 960)
    )))


server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

output$loc <- renderInfoBox({
if (input$Ben == "1"){
  box(h3("1"),
      infoBox("Total", 30, "Visits", icon = icon('users'), width = 4),
      infoBox("M", 10 ,"Visits", icon = icon('male'), width = 4),
      infoBox("F", 20 ,"Visits", icon = icon('female'), width = 4),
      loadEChartsLibrary(),  tags$div(id="test1", style="width:60%;height:300px;"),
              deliverChart(div_id = "test1"), width = "800px", height = "400px",
      renderPieChart(div_id = "test1", data = dat1, show.label = TRUE),
      background = "black")       
}
else {if (input$Ben == "2") {
  box(h3("2"),
      infoBox("Total", 40, "Visits", icon = icon('users'), width = 4),
      infoBox("M", 20 ,"Visits", icon = icon('male'), width = 4),
      infoBox("F", 20 ,"Visits", icon = icon('female'), width = 4),
      loadEChartsLibrary(),  tags$div(id="test2", style="width:60%;height:300px;"),
              deliverChart(div_id = "test2"), width = "800px", height = "400px",
      renderPieChart(div_id = "test2", data = dat2, show.label = TRUE),
      background = "black") 
}    
      else{
          box(h3("3"),
              infoBox("Total", 50 , icon = icon('users'), width = 4),
              infoBox("m", 30, icon = icon("male"), width = 4),
              infoBox("f", 20,  icon = icon('female'), width = 4),
              loadEChartsLibrary(),  tags$div(id="test3", style="width:60%;height:300px;"),
              deliverChart(div_id = "test3"), width = "800px", height = "400px",
              renderPieChart(div_id = "test1", data = dat1, show.label = TRUE), background ="black")

        }}  }}}

    })

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

While select the radio button, the **infoBox()** and the relevant **pie chart** should be shown in the shinyApp.
Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the `renderPieChart` statement:

```
renderPieChart(div_id = "test1", data = dat1, show.label = TRUE)
```

The data used for the pie charts is not in the format needed for `renderPieChart`. A `data.frame` is being supplied, but it should be in this format:

> If it's a data.frame, the data must be made up of only two columns,
>   "name" and "value". The "value" column must be numeric or integer.

So, for `dat1` (and other data) you can do the following (for 10 male, 20 female):

```
dat1 <- data.frame(
  name = c("Male", "Female"),
  value = c(10, 20)
)
```

Then it should draw the pie charts.

Also note that the third pie chart should have `div_id = "test 3"` I suspect.